# Incompatibilidade android 4.4.2 com ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic2

Fiz um aplicativo em ionic 2 e tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém, um usuário ao utilizar no celular com android 4.4.2, algumas funcionalidades, como por exemplo, o upload de arquivos, não funciona.

Não gera erros, simplesmente não faz o upload.

Além do tempo do loading inicial, antes do splash, demorar quase 1 minuto para carregar.

Alguém tem alguma ideia se é alguma incompatibilidade do ionic com essa versão do android?

Comment: Eu utilizo em um celular com 4.4.2 e já emulei em uma versão mais antiga e roda, um pouco lento mas roda. Em celular mais antigos o melhor é usar o croswalk, mas ai aumenta muito ao tamanho do app. Veja se consegue dar um console.log no exception do seu upload.